Prevent staging ground posts from being approved when they are in a "require changes" or "declined re-evaluation" state
Yesterday I reviewed this staging ground post and requested "Major Changes" with a reasonably detailed comment about what needed improving.
The author made a very minor change to the title only and another reviewer quite rightly declined the re-evaluation.
Not long after that though, a third reviewer approved the post. Since then it has garnered four downvotes and has been closed.
Timeline: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78962430/timeline
This post should never have been approved, especially given the review state it was in. In my opinion this is extremely unfair to the author and will probably leave them with a very poor Stack Overflow experience.
Feature request: Prevent staging ground posts from being approved if reviewers have indicated they are not ready for the main site.
Or at the very least show some kind of warning to the would-be approver...

Other reviewers have indicated this question is not ready to be posted. Are you sure you want to approve it?


If you don't want posts in Re-Evaluate being approved, how do you want to approve posts that should be approved? That's the entire point of the Re-Evaluate state. The issue is more that some reviewers don't really understand what's expected from them.

@dan1st I never said posts in "re-evaluate" shouldn't be approved. That is indeed the whole point of the evaluation cycle

The edit moved the post to Re-Evaluate. Aside from that, posts actually in "Requires Major Changes" don't often get picked up and approved by reviewers (thiugh clearing the off-topic state is often necessary).

@dan1st Yes and then AxB declined it for re-evaluation, and rightly so. If the timeline isn't clear from my description above, it should be more easily understood here - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78962430/timeline

Agreed; declining re-evaluation should send it back to the "major changes needed" stage and immediately remove it from the pile of posts available for review.

Besides this... It's kind of hard to understand why the proven wisdom found in reviewing where multiple votes are needed is ignored for the staging ground. One person with a mission to be nice and protective of new users can derail everything.
